# Realm - commitWriteTransaction:outError

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm

I have a UserObject and it has a "course" property. I tried updating "course" but it's not working.

Here's my code:

```
if let user = realm.objects(UserObject).filter(predicate).first {
        user.course = value
        do {
            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(user, update: true)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Something went wrong: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }
```

When I debugged my code, *transactionWithBlock* returns [*self commitWriteTransaction:outError]*

```
- (BOOL)transactionWithBlock:(void(^)(void))block error:(NSError **)outError {
[self beginWriteTransaction];
block();
if (_realm->is_in_transaction()) {
    return [self commitWriteTransaction:outError];
}
return YES;
```

}

Could you help me understand why? Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that your code is "not working"?

Comment: @bdash what i meant was i cannot save new value for "course"

Answer (score 1):

Once an object has been saved to Realm, you cannot modify its properties outside of a write transaction. In this case, you've queried for an object, tried to modify its property outside of a write transaction, and then tried to re-insert it with `realm.add(_, update:)`, which is redundant since that's only necessary when working with objects that weren't already managed by Realm.

The correct way to update `user.course` in this case would be:

```
if let user = realm.objects(UserObject).filter(predicate).first {
    do {
        try! user.realm.write {
            user.course = value
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Something went wrong: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```